# How to Create Generic @Service That Injects Specific @Repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

Our software have a specific behaviour that applies to all the functionalities, what change in most cases is the Entity used in operations, and for that we need specific implementation for @Repository layer.

So, we develop an "simple" architecture `@RestController` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository` with some generics, to work for all the functionality. Like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
// This is specific implementation
public class DiariasApi implements DefaultApiInterface<DiariasDTO, DiariasDTOFilter, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private DefaultService<DiariasDTO, DiariasDTOFilter, Integer> defaultService;

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/page")
    public Page<DiariasDTO> pageSearch(final DiariasDTOFilter filter) {
        return this.defaultService.pageSearch(filter);
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/detail")
    public DiariasDTO detail(@PathVariable("key") final Integer key) {
        return this.defaultService.detail(key);
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
// This is generic implementation
public class DefaultService<D extends Serializable, F extends Serializable, C> {

    @Autowired
    // The Problem is here.
   // Here I want the call to be the specific @Repository.
    private DefaultRepositoryInterface<D, F, C> defaultRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<D> pageSearch(final F filter) {
        return this.defaultRepository.pageSearch(filter);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public D detail(final C key) {
        return this.defaultRepository.detail(key);
    }

}
```

```java
@Repository
// This is specific implementation
public class DiariasRepository implements DefaultRepositoryInterface<DiariasDTO, DiariasDTOFilter, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Page<DiariasDTO> pageSearch(final DiariasFiltro filtro) {
        //some specific code;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<DiariasDTO> detail(final Integer key) {
        //some specific code;
    }
```

We want to implement only the `@RestController` and the `@Repository` for each functionality, and let the `@Service` layer be only one generic bean that knows how to call the specific `@Repository`. But when we do that and have more than one implementation we receive the following error message, which tells us the problem with `@Autowired`:

```
Description:
Field defaultRepository in package.DefaultService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - conveniosRepository: defined in file ...
    - diariasRepository: defined in file ...
```

We want the `@Service` layer to be unique, can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@Qualifier` which will bind the specific bean instance

```
@Service
// This is generic implementation
 public class DefaultService<D extends Serializable, F extends Serializable, C> {

@Autowired
// The Problem is here.
// Here I want the call to be the specific @Repository.
@Qualifier("YourBeanId")
private DefaultRepositoryInterface<D, F, C> defaultRepository;
```

**EDIT**

So you can use another approach which I had used in past for local v/s testing environment

The factory like class that will return the specific instance of the bean at runtime

Create a Factory class

```
@Component
public class RepositoryFactoryImpl implements RepositoryFactory{

@Autowired
private DefaultRepositoryInterface conveniosRepository;

@Autowired
private DefaultRepositoryInterface diariasRepository;

@Override
public DefaultRepositoryInterface getInstance() {
    if (some condition) {
        return conveniosRepository;
    }

    if (some condition) {
        return diariasRepository;
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

Then in your `DefaultService`

```
@Service
// This is generic implementation
public class DefaultService<D extends Serializable, F extends Serializable, C> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryFactory factory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<D> pageSearch(final F filter) {
        return this.factory.getInstance().pageSearch(filter);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public D detail(final C key) {
        return this.factory.getInstance().detail(key);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I can't use @Qualifier there, because the `DefaultService` is generic. The "YourBeanId" changes depend on who is call him.

Comment: What is the point of using DefaultRepositoryInterface? Why don't you use CrudRepository, for instance?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I omit some of the methods that we have on the Service and Repository. We have some complex methods and querys that can't be achieved with CrudRepository.

Comment: @NullPointerException, in the edition you did, what can I use in "some condition"? I think this still be the problem in this scenario.

Comment: This will be your condition to identify the repository instance to be picked

Comment: But in the factory, I don't have any kind of information like this, to identify the caller.

Comment: You had to pass that. How were you originally identifying or planning to identifying the same condition in your service ?  you just need to put the pieces together. If you need you can pass the parameters to `getInstance` method from service to factory.

Comment: The Inicial ideia was that it works just the way we first made. That Spring can identify the correct Respository only looking the generics. From what we see on for Spring 4.0+, it can identify the correct bean to inject without the Qualifier, but in this case the parameter is generic too, so it dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is perfectly fine, I have a similar one. 
Your problem --I think is, that you want a generic service to access a specific repository. Make a `DiariasService` that extends `Service<DiariasDto, DiariasFilter, Integer>` and let Spring autowire in a 
`DiariasRepository` that extends `Repository<DiariasDto, DiariasFilter, Integer>` *in the constuctor* and pass it to the abstract service.

You have a new but pretty much empty Service, but correctly resolved the ambiguous dependencies.

My java isn't the freshest, so in kotlin this looks like:

```
abstract class Service<R : Resource, M : Model>(
    protected open val factory: Factory<R, M>,
    //...
)

class FooService(
    factory: FooFactory, //spring bean type magic happens here and @Qualifier is applicable!
    //...
) : Service<FooResource, FooModel>(
    factory, //from one constuctor to the superclass constructor
    //...
)

abstract class Factory<R : Resource, M : Model>(
    //...
)

class FooFactory(
    //...
) : Factory<FooResource, FooModel>(
    //...
)
```

I use the same pattern for `Controller`/`FooController` and `Repository`/`FooRepository` and so on.

Of course there are abstract `Model` and `Resource`/`Entity`.

You cannot use `@Qualifier` in the abstract `Service`/`Controller`/`Repository`/`Factory`, but in the concrete classes!